# Static inner classes in scala

Tags: java, scala, static, inner-classes

What is the analog in Scala of doing this in Java:

```
public class Outer {
  private Inner inner;

  public static class Inner {
  }

  public Inner getInner() { return inner; }
}
```

I specifically want my inner class to **not** have to have a fully qualified name - i.e. I want `Trade.Type`, not `TradeType`. So in Scala I imagined it might be something like:

```
class Outer(val inner: Inner) {
    object Inner
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work: my scala `Inner` just doesn't seem to be visible from outside the `Outer` class. One solution would of course be:

```
class Inner
class Outer(val inner: Inner)
```

Which is OK - but because of the names of my classes, `Inner` is really the "type" of the `Outer` and `Outer` actually has a long name. So:

```
class SomeHorriblyLongNameType
class SomeHorriblyLongName(myType: SomeHorriblyLongNameType)
```

Which is verbose and horrible. I could replace `SomeHorriblyLongNameType` with just `Type` but there would then be no obvious connection between it and the class it was related to. Phew

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do something like this if don't need access to the outer class in the inner class (which you wouldn't have in Java given that your inner class was declared `static`):

```
object A{
    class B {
        val x = 3
    }
}
class A {
    // implementation of class here
}
println(new A.B().x)
```

Answer (score 25):

As others have pointed out, "static" classes should be placed inside the companion object.

In Scala, classes, traits, and objects which are members of a class are path-dependent. For example:

```
class Button {
  class Click
}


val ok = new Button
val cancel = new Button

val c1 = new ok.Click
val c2 = new cancel.Click
```

Now c1 and c2 are instances of -different- classes. One class is ok.Click, and the other is cancel.Click. If you wanted to refer to the type of all Click classes, you could say Button#Click.

Comment: This class is inner but not static

Answer (score 6):

[From scala-lang](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1381):

> there is no notion of 'static' members
>   in Scala.  Instead, Scala treats
>   static members of class Y as members
>   of the singleton object Y

So it seems you could have a class defined inside an Object, but not a static class defined inside a class.

Comment: If you declare an object inside a class in Scala, it is then not visible from outside that class (or I couldn't figure out how to make it so). Your answer is not quite what I was asking: I was asking how I could do something in Scala, as opposed to asking how Scala would treat Java statics

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understood your use case... If it can help you, objects inside classes are visible like an instance's fields, e.g.

```
case class C(var x: Int)
class A { case object b extends C(0) }
val a = new A
println(a.b.x)
a.b.x = 2
println(a.b.x)
```

Moreover, you can perfectly override a parent's val with object:

```
case class C(var x: Int)
class A { val y: C = C(0) }
class B extends A { override case object y extends C(2) }
val a: A = new B
println(a.y.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

In scala if you need to create a some static methods you can use a companion object, with the same name of the class, where you store all the pseudo static methods. Ex:

```
class A {
}

object A {
    def xpto // define some pseudo static methods here..
}
```

Then you can just use `A.xpto`.
Try to read more about companion modules on scala